# Liferay.PortletURL in JavaScript creates an URL with /c/portal/layout

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE. And I want to create a portlet URL with Javascript. Here's my code:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-util-window,liferay-portlet-url">
  var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
  portletURL.setParameter('action', 'detailCourse');
  portletURL.setParameter('id', 10);
  console.log("render = " + portletURL.toString());
</aui:script>
```

*portletURL.toString()* results in:

```
http://localhost:8080/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=29913&p_p_lifecycle=0&_undefined_action=detailCourse&_undefined_id=19
```

But it should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/group/backdoor/home?p_p_id=classlistbackdoor_WAR_classlistbackdoor100SNAPSHOT&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_classlistbackdoor_WAR_classlistbackdoor100SNAPSHOT_id=10&_classlistbackdoor_WAR_classlistbackdoor100SNAPSHOT_action=detailCourse
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Creating Portlet URLs in JavaScript](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-portlet-urls-in-javascript-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-07-en) this was changed in Liferay 6.2:

> After the fix for the security issue, generating friendly portlet URLs via JavaScript is no longer possible.

But there is a solution given, which works (at least for JSPs):

```
var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createURL(
   '<%= PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, 
          portletId, 
          themeDisplay.getPlid(), 
          PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE) %>');
```